# Pointer to values getting overwritten (Access exception)

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, winsock

so mine object pointer of a class have some problems and keeps getting overwritten on a function. To help you understand, this is a project that is ment to be a library for helping people with easily making winsock socket connections with server from client.

Main.cpp:

```
(includes aleready included)

int main() {

Client client;

//AUTH SERVER
client.WSA_init(2, 2);
SOCKET server_auth = client.init("127.0.0.1", 3211);

std::string auth = client.ClientRecieve(server_auth);
std::string hash = client.Auth(auth);

client.End(server_auth);

client.WSA_init(2, 2);
SOCKET server_main = client.init("127.0.0.1", 3212);

client.ClientSend(server_main, (char*)hash.c_str());

ClientSocketParameters* t_params = new ClientSocketParameters; //Basically a parameter object pointer
t_params->Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode = THREAD_CONSOLE_PRINT_INFO; //These are defined aleready as macros in the win32s.h file
t_params->Recv_Raw = false;
t_params->Recv_Server_Type = SERVER_TYPE_JAVA;
t_params->Send_Mode = THREAD_KEYBOARD_SEND;
t_params->Send_Raw = false;
t_params->Send_Server_Type = SERVER_TYPE_JAVA;

client.setThreadParameters(t_params); //Sets the params

DWORD tid;

ThreadHandler::Socket_CallBack* t_recv = new ThreadHandler::Socket_CallBack;
t_recv->client = &client;
t_recv->socket = server_main;
ThreadHandler::Socket_CallBack* t_send = new ThreadHandler::Socket_CallBack;
t_send->client = &client;
t_send->socket = server_main;

HANDLE h1 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve, &t_recv, 0, &tid); //Launches functions that are starting recv and sending with infinity loop (cant put here a client method so needed to do this (btw. these are also in the win32s files))
HANDLE h2 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientSend, &t_send, 0, &tid);

WaitForSingleObject(h1, INFINITE);
WaitForSingleObject(h2, INFINITE);

client.End(server_main);

return 0;
}
```

win32_s.h file:

```
(includes aleready included)

class ClientSocketParameters { //Parameter class
public:
//Recieving
DWORD Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode;
bool Recv_Raw;
DWORD Recv_Server_Type;
std::string* Recv_StoreAddress;
char* Recv_StoreAdress_Raw;
//Sending
DWORD Send_Mode;
bool Send_Raw;
DWORD Send_Server_Type;
std::string* Send_StoredDataAddress;
};

class Client {
private:

ClientSocketParameters* thread_settings = new ClientSocketParameters; //This is the pointer that is getting overwritten. It is basically a pointer to the parameters that you set with a method in your main

SOCKET init(std::string ip, int port); //Most of these functions are not necessary for problem cause
WSAData WSA_init(int version_makeword_1, int version_makeword_2);
std::string Auth(std::string key);
int PackageManager(); //TODO
int ClientSend(SOCKET dst, char buffer[]);
std::string ClientRecieve(SOCKET src);
std::string BufferToString(char buffer[]);
std::string BufferToJavaString(char buffer[]);
std::string JavaBufferToString(char buffer[]);
int End(SOCKET con);

Some macros

void setThreadParameters(ClientSocketParameters* params);

DWORD WINAPI Thread_ClientRecieve(LPVOID socket_src);
DWORD WINAPI Thread_ClientSend(LPVOID dst);
};

namespace ThreadHandler { //These lauches the thread functions with calling them (check .cpp of this file)
DWORD WINAPI ThreadClientRecieve(LPVOID param);
DWORD WINAPI ThreadClientSend(LPVOID param);

struct Socket_CallBack {
    SOCKET socket;
    Client* client;
};

}
```

win32_s.cpp file:

```
#include "win32_s.h"
(I'm not going to show the not necessary functions that work)

void Client::setThreadParameters(ClientSocketParameters* params) {
std::cout << params << std::endl;
thread_settings = params;
std::cout << thread_settings << std::endl; //This address is correct to this point, The Thread_ClientRecieve and the thread send function overwrites the address to 0x11C when checking the variables of the pointer
}

DWORD WINAPI Client::Thread_ClientRecieve(LPVOID lpParam) { //TODO: Packet management, Exceptions

const DWORD MAX_BYTES = 1024;
char buffer[MAX_BYTES];
size_t recvbytes;
SOCKET server = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;

while (true) {

    //std::cout << "here #packet recieve" << std::endl;

    ZeroMemory(buffer, MAX_BYTES);
    
    recvbytes = recv(server, buffer, MAX_BYTES, 0);

    if (recvbytes <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Recieving info from server failed. Cancellig thread..." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    std::cout << thread_settings->Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode << std::endl;
    std::cout << thread_settings->Recv_Raw << std::endl;
    std::cout << thread_settings->Recv_Server_Type << std::endl;

    if (thread_settings->Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode == THREAD_CONSOLE_PRINT_INFO) {

        std::string console_text;

        if (thread_settings->Recv_Raw) {
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        if (thread_settings->Recv_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_JAVA) {
            console_text = JavaBufferToString(buffer);
            std::cout << console_text << std::endl;
        }
        if (thread_settings->Recv_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_WINSOCK) {
            console_text = BufferToString(buffer);
            std::cout << console_text << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (thread_settings->Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode == THREAD_STORE_INFO) {

        std::string buffer_s;

        if (thread_settings->Recv_Raw) {
            thread_settings->Recv_StoreAdress_Raw = buffer;
        }
        if (thread_settings->Recv_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_JAVA) {
            buffer_s = JavaBufferToString(buffer);
            *thread_settings->Recv_StoreAddress = buffer_s;
        }
        if (thread_settings->Recv_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_WINSOCK) {
            buffer_s = BufferToString(buffer);
            *thread_settings->Recv_StoreAddress = buffer_s;
        }
    }

}

return 0;

}

DWORD WINAPI Client::Thread_ClientSend(LPVOID lpParam) {

const DWORD MAX_BYTES = 1024;
char buffer[1024];
SOCKET server = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;

while (true) {

    //std::cout << "here #send packet" << std::endl;

    if (thread_settings->Send_Mode == THREAD_KEYBOARD_SEND) {
        std::cin.getline(buffer, 1024);
        std::string data;

        if (thread_settings->Send_Raw) {
            if (send(server, buffer, MAX_BYTES, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "Failed while sending to the server. Closing thread...." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (thread_settings->Send_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_JAVA) {
            data = BufferToJavaString(buffer);
            if (send(server, data.c_str(), data.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "Failed while sending to the server. Closing thread...." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (thread_settings->Send_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_WINSOCK) {
            data = BufferToString(buffer);
            if (send(server, data.c_str(), data.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "Failed while sending to the server. Closing thread...." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

    }

    if (thread_settings->Send_Mode == THREAD_VARIABLE_SEND) {

        if (thread_settings->Send_StoredDataAddress == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Please enter a address to use the thread variable send function. Cancelling thread..." << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        //memset(thread_settings.Send_StoredDataAddress, 0x90, sizeof(thread_settings.Send_StoredDataAddress));
        std::string StoredData = *thread_settings->Send_StoredDataAddress;

        if (thread_settings->Send_Server_Type == SERVER_TYPE_JAVA) {
            StoredData.append("\n");

            if (send(server, StoredData.c_str(), StoredData.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "Failed while sending to the server. Closing thread...." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (send(server, StoredData.c_str(), StoredData.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                std::cout << "Failed while sending to the server. Closing thread...." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve(LPVOID param) {

Socket_CallBack* s_callback = new Socket_CallBack;
s_callback = (Socket_CallBack*)param;

SOCKET socket = s_callback->socket;

Client* callback_ptr = new Client;
callback_ptr = s_callback->client;

//delete s_callback;
//delete &s_callback->client;

std::cout << "ClientRecvSocketAddr: " << socket << std::endl;
std::cout << "ClientCallBackPtr: " << callback_ptr << std::endl;

return callback_ptr->Thread_ClientRecieve((LPVOID)socket);

}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler::ThreadClientSend(LPVOID param) {

Socket_CallBack* s_callback = new Socket_CallBack;
s_callback = (Socket_CallBack*)param;

SOCKET socket = s_callback->socket;

Client* callback_ptr = new Client;
callback_ptr = s_callback->client;

//delete s_callback;
//delete &s_callback->client;

std::cout << "ClientSendSocketAddr: " << socket << std::endl;
std::cout << "ClientCallBackPtr: " << callback_ptr << std::endl;

return callback_ptr->Thread_ClientSend((LPVOID)socket);

}
```

This code is not fully done yet so things like checking and smaller details arent still implemented.
Thanks for any help and using your time at this.

Comment: If you have a bug and don't know what it is, how can you be sure the code you left out  is indeed irrelevant? Most of the time the reason people can't find the bug is they're looking in the wrong spot. Crafting a [mre] will eliminate that possibility. And, because MRE is a powerful debugging tool, probably let you find and fix the bug without our help.

Comment: Postponing checking for errors until they start occurring is false economy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
SOCKET server_main = client.init("127.0.0.1", 3212);
...
HANDLE h1 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve, &server_main, 0, &tid);
HANDLE h2 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientSend, &server_main, 0, &tid);
```

You create two threads passing a pointer to a `SOCKET` as the parameter.

But in the thread code you cast that parameter to a `Client` pointer.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler::ThreadClientSend(LPVOID param) {
    Client* ptr = (Client*)param;
    return ptr->Thread_ClientSend(param);
}
```

Not surprisingly casting something that is really a `SOCKET*` to a `Client*` isn't going to work.

I guess the code should look like this

```
HANDLE h1 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve, &client, 0, &tid);
HANDLE h2 = CreateThread(nullptr, NULL, ThreadHandler::ThreadClientSend, &client, 0, &tid);
```

**EDIT** so there are still various issues

This code is not wrong, it's just wasteful (and confusing)

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve(LPVOID param) {

    Socket_CallBack* s_callback = new Socket_CallBack;
    s_callback = (Socket_CallBack*)param;

    SOCKET socket = s_callback->socket;

    Client* callback_ptr = new Client;
    callback_ptr = s_callback->client;
```

There's absolutely no need to allocate more memory here, the `Socket_CallBack` and `Client` objects have already been allocated. This code will work

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadHandler::ThreadClientRecieve(LPVOID param) {

    Socket_CallBack* s_callback =  (Socket_CallBack*)param;
    SOCKET socket = s_callback->socket;
    Client* callback_ptr = s_callback->client;
```

Now here's the real error

```
return callback_ptr->Thread_ClientRecieve((LPVOID)socket);
```

A `SOCKET` is being passed to `Thread_ClientRecieve`. But when we look at `Thread_ClientRecieve`

```
DWORD WINAPI Client::Thread_ClientRecieve(LPVOID lpParam) {
    ...
    SOCKET server = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;
```

The parameter is being cast as a `SOCKET*`. When you cast one type to something else, you have to cast back to the same type. You can't cast a `SOCKET` back to a `SOCKET*`.

Two ways to fix this, one minimal, one the right way to do it (avoiding as much as possible casting and pointers).

The minimal way is to pass the address of the socket, like this

```
return callback_ptr->Thread_ClientRecieve((LPVOID)&socket);
```

Now a `SOCKET*` is being passed to `Client::Thread_ClientRecieve`, so you can safely cast your parameter back to a `SOCKET*`.

But here we can simply remove all the pointers and casting by changing the parameter of `Client::Thread_ClientRecieve` to be a `SOCKET`, no casting, no pointers.

```
DWORD WINAPI Client::Thread_ClientRecieve(SOCKET server) {
    ...
```

and when you call it just pass the socket, no casting needed

```
return callback_ptr->Thread_ClientRecieve(socket);
```

The send code looks to have similar errors.

Comment: Yep, thats true, going to check it out in a minute, I'm going to pass the client object but i also would then need to set the socket of the recv and send. Can easily do it with a method.

Comment: I've now made a struct that contains a socket* and a client*, then i cast it as a lpvoid and in the threadhandler function i uncast it and get the two vars. When i tried debugging it then i saw that it was getting overwritten then. It is every time now overwritten into 0xCCCCCCC

Comment: Make sure the struct is not going out of scope and being destroyed before the threads have a chance to grab it. Same with the `Client` object. You should be allocating them dynamically and then freeing them later when the threads are done using them. Also, there is no need to pass a `SOCKET` around by pointer at all, it is just an integer so pass it around by value instead.

Comment: CCCCCCCC is often [the program trying to tell you something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values). In general whenever you see a pattern that's highly repetitive or looks like English words, look it up.

Comment: Have tried both, registering on the heap and on the stack but still, nothing works. I've also tried to delete varaibles before the thread could get them. Nothing that i tried works. Same with the 0xCCCCCCCC debug value (The exception haven't change while changing anything in the code).

Comment: @Paabl0 Would need to see the latest code to help. As stated above the CCCCCCCC bit pattern mans you are accessing uninitialised memory which (perhaps) means you've just made some simple mistake with your casts and pointers.

Comment: @john, sorry for not uploading the code for 2 days but i was thinking about solving it my self cause i dont really like when people solve things for me. I was trying to solve the problem myself but didn't get anywhere so i decided again to upload it here.

Comment: @Paabl0 Still some errors, that a look at my latest edit.

Comment: @john I fixed the issue with the ThreadHandler threads like you explained but still something is missing.... **this** is still going crazy to 0xCCCCCCCC and i don't understand. I checked the debugger and when the setParameters() function in the .cpp was called all the vars and **this** where still fine. Soon after when the threads are launching **this** address is going over to 0xCCC.. value and it can't read the parameter value that setParameters() is setting cause it can't read that memory. I'm going to continue my journey with this thingy, maybe a solution is right in front of me.